# Convert curl command to httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, mailchimp

I am trying to add merge field in Mailchimp V3 list with HTTParty but not able to convert curl to HTTParty format.
Curl Request format which is working fine :

```
curl --request POST \
     --url 'https://usxx.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/17efad7sd4/merge-fields' \
     --user '12:d1c1d99dr5000c63f0f73f64b88e852e-xx' \
     --header 'content-type: application/json' \
     --data '{"name":"FAVORITEJOKE", "type":"text"}' \
     --include
```

Httparty format with error API key missing

```
response = HTTParty.post("https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/17efad7sde/merge-fields", 
                :body => { 
                  :user => '12:d1c1d99dr5000c63f0f73f64b88e852e-xx',
                  :data =>  '{"name":"FAVORITEJOKE", "type":"text"}',
                  :include => ''
                }.to_json,
                :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } )
```

I also try it without include option but not working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.

- curl `user` is the basic auth user, but you are passing it in the payload of the request
- data is the payload, instead you are passing it as a node in your payload and then you double serialize it
- include makes no sense there, it's not a payload item

This should be the correct version. Please take a moment to read the `HTTParty` and `curl` documentation and understand the differences.

```
HTTParty.post(
  "https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/17efad7sde/merge-fields", 
  basic_auth: { username: "12", password: "d1c1d99dr5000c63f0f73f64b88e852e-xx" },
  headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' },
  body: {
    name: "FAVORITEJOKE",
    type: "text",
  }.to_json
)
```

Comment: curl -> httparty converter would be epic.

Comment: @Abram there's a curl -> Net:HTTP converter at https://curlconverter.com/ruby/